# Break FTP upload before it's done

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I'm need a test program to automate an upload to an FTP where I want to close the connection before the file have been uploaded as I need this to check how our server handles broken file uploads. I want to "kill" the connection rather than closing it.

Anyone got some suggestion how to do this in C#?

Comment: This question does not belong here since it is not a real question but merely a code request.

Comment: I'm not asking for the full program, just how to force close on a ongoing upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you upload? Using `FtpWebRequest`? If yes, use:

```
FtpWebRequest.Abort()
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx).

If you upload in separate thread, just kill this thread.